# Deleting column with cut or awk from a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, edit, cut

I have the following file in unix:

```
1098000000199400000099400000010110000000000007000+00000000000001400000032
2010199434117300000017300000010110000000000007000+00000000000000400000009
1010199434117300000017300000010110000000000007000+00000000000000400000009
```

I need to delete the column that has the "+" in the position 50th using awk or cut command.
I was trying to use something like the code below but it handles it like fields, I need to handle this like columns:

```
awk '{ $50 = ""; print>"new.txt" }' file.txt
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I suspect you are confusing column and row.

Comment: If `tr -d '+' < file` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide more/clearer information and probably a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want columns 1 to 49 and everything above 50:

```
cut -c1-49,51- file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @Walter A's answer is perfect, I'll give another method, which is slower, but more broadly applicable:

Open the input file with vim:

```
vim input.txt
```

You'll be in "normal mode". Go to column 50 by typing `50|`.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and you will enter "block selection mode".

Then you can navigate with the arrows to mark a column, or a block of multiple columns (any square of text, really), and then press <kbd>d</kbd> to delete that block.

This allows you to essentially edit column in bulk, interactively. It also allows you to do other operations besides deleting, e.g. copying to clipboard (by using <kbd>"+y</kbd> instead of <kbd>d</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed for doing it.

sed -i '/string_to_be_replaced/replace_by/g' filename

sed -i 's/+//g' filename

Because here you just want to replace the '+' by nothing

sed -i will edit the original file

Use sed -e 's/+//g' filename > newfile for writing to a separate file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk ++NF FS='+' OFS=
> ```

```
109800000019940000009940000001011000000000000700000000000000001400000032
201019943411730000001730000001011000000000000700000000000000000400000009
101019943411730000001730000001011000000000000700000000000000000400000009
```